# Reinstall component when rerunning WiX installer

Tags: wix

I am creating a Windows installer using WiX version 3.14. My installer allows me to change the path where the components are installed.

If I run the installer and choose a path, the components are installed to my chosen location no problem.

If I then re-run the installer and change the location, the components are not moved to the new location. I'm assuming this is because the components are already installed and the installer does not think they need to be moved to the new location.

Is there a way to force components to uninstall/reinstall when re-running the same installer?

Comment: The dialog to change the installation path is typically not shown in maintenance mode. Have you changed the dialog set? If so, can we ask why the files need to be moved? There may be alternatives.

Comment: Also, do you mean WiX 3.10.4? Latest official WiX is 3.11.1. Maybe you are using a pre-release?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, yes i am using the latest pre-release of WiX. Earlier version of WiX are dependent on .NET 3.5 and I do not want to install .NET 3.5 on my Window 10 machine.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, yes I have changed the dialog set. I have two dialogs that prompt for install directories for two different audio plugin components. Each dialog has a Text Control and a PushButton Control (that opens a custom folder dialog). I am open to suggestions as to alternative ways to avoid the issue.

Comment: Would it be an option to hide the custom dialogs during the maintenance mode dialog sequence? Or have you added the custom dialogs with the intent to support this directory migration? Sorry, it is not quite clear to me if this is an "accidental feature" or intended.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, in one case it is an accidental feature, in the other case, it makes sense for the user to be able to choose a new location if they re-run the installer.